# I try to separate 2 box layouts but instead they fuse together

Tags: python, kivy

I want to separate these 2 box layouts but when I run it, they are literally one over another. I've looked through kivy documents and still didn't find an answer.

Here is my code:

```
<BoxLayout>:
    spacing:"0dp"
    orientation:"vertical"
    Label:
        text:"test"
        background_color: (64/255, 64/255, 64/255,1)
        size_hint:1,1
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: self.background_color
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
    Label:
        text:"test"
        background_color: (64/255, 64/255, 64/255,1)
        size_hint:.2,.3
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: self.background_color
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
    Label:
        text:"test"
        background_color: (64/255, 64/255, 64/255,1)
        size_hint:.2,.3
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: self.background_color
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos

<BoxLayout>:
    orientation:"vertical"
    spacing:"10dp"
    TextInput:
        text: "type enemy name"
        size_hint:1,3
        id: starta
    Button:
        text:"Start"
        on_press: root.on_button_click()
        size_hint:1,3
        font_size:40
        id: startb
    Label:
        id: label
        text: "Enter enemy name and press 'start'"
        text_size: self.width-100, None
        font_size:27
    Button:
        text:"Fight"
        size_hint: 1,.3
        color:1,0,0,1
        background_color:.5,0,0
        font_size:40
        opacity:0
        id: thingy
    Button:
        text:"Guard"
        size_hint: 1,.3
        color:0,0,1,1
        background_color:0,0,.5
        font_size:40
        opacity:0
        id: thingys
    Button:
        text:"Heal"
        size_hint: 1,.3
        color:0,1,0,1
        background_color:0,.5,0
        font_size:40
        opacity:0
        id: thingyss
```

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import (NumericProperty, StringProperty)
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from random import randint
from time import sleep
from threading import Thread
import time
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader
turn=False
started=False
attacking=False
healing=False
guard=False
guardcor=False
enemycharge=False
enemyhp=200
playerhp=200
maxmana=50
mana=50
enemydamage=20
playerdamage=13
testify=[]

Builder.load_string("""
<BoxLayout>:
    spacing:"0dp"
    orientation:"vertical"
    Label:
        text:"test"
        background_color: (64/255, 64/255, 64/255,1)
        size_hint:1,1
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: self.background_color
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
    Label:
        text:"test"
        background_color: (64/255, 64/255, 64/255,1)
        size_hint:.2,.3
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: self.background_color
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
    Label:
        text:"test"
        background_color: (64/255, 64/255, 64/255,1)
        size_hint:.2,.3
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: self.background_color
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos

<BoxLayout>:
    orientation:"vertical"
    spacing:"10dp"
    TextInput:
        text: "type enemy name"
        size_hint:1,3
        id: starta
    Button:
        text:"Start"
        on_press: root.on_button_click()
        size_hint:1,3
        font_size:40
        id: startb
    Label:
        id: label
        text: "Enter enemy name and press 'start'"
        text_size: self.width-100, None
        font_size:27
    Button:
        text:"Fight"
        size_hint: 1,.3
        color:1,0,0,1
        background_color:.5,0,0
        font_size:40
        opacity:0
        id: thingy
    Button:
        text:"Guard"
        size_hint: 1,.3
        color:0,0,1,1
        background_color:0,0,.5
        font_size:40
        opacity:0
        id: thingys
    Button:
        text:"Heal"
        size_hint: 1,.3
        color:0,1,0,1
        background_color:0,.5,0
        font_size:40
        opacity:0
        id: thingyss
        
""")

from time import sleep
from threading import Thread


class ProcessingThread(Thread):
    global testify
    global enemyhp
    global playerhp
    global maxmana
    global mana
    global enemydamage
    global playerdamage
    global attacking
    global healing
    global guard
    global turn
    global enemycharge
    global guardcor
    def run(self):
        global attacking
        global healing
        global guard
        global turn
        global testify
        global enemyhp
        global playerhp
        global maxmana
        global mana
        global enemydamage
        global playerdamage
        global enemycharge
        global guardcor
        label = testify[0]
        fightb = testify[1]
        guardb = testify[2]
        healb = testify[3]
        enemyname=testify[4]
        rootui=testify[5]
        #enemyhpui=testify[6]
        #playerhpui=testify[7]
        #manaui=testify[8]
        fightb.opacity = 1
        guardb.opacity = 1
        healb.opacity = 1

        TextBox.type_text(rootui, "who you are fighting againist is %s, be careful. they are strong."% enemyname)
        sleep(7)
        label.color=1,0,0,1
        TextBox.type_text(rootui, "FIGHT makes you deal 13 damage to the enemy.")
        sleep(5)
        label.color=0,0,1,1
        TextBox.type_text(rootui,"GUARD makes you not get hit when the enemy attacks.")
        sleep(5.5)
        label.color=0,1,0,1
        TextBox.type_text(rootui, "and lastly, HEAL makes you heal 30 health.")
        sleep(5)
        label.color=1,1,1,1
        TextBox.type_text(rootui, "good luck, player.")
        sleep(3)
        soundyeye = SoundLoader.load('battlesong.mp3')
        soundyeye.loop=True
        soundyeye.play()
        TextBox.type_text(rootui, "%s jumps into the battlefield!"% enemyname)
        while True:
            dialoguerng=randint(1,4)
            if dialoguerng==1:
                TextBox.type_text(rootui,"%s looks around him and then looks back to you."% enemyname)
                sleep(6)
            elif dialoguerng==2:
                TextBox.type_text(rootui,"%s readies itself."% enemyname)
                sleep(3)
            elif dialoguerng==3:
                TextBox.type_text(rootui,"%s is too excited to beat you up"% enemyname)
                sleep(5)
            elif dialoguerng==4:
                TextBox.type_text(rootui, "%s is sick of this battling system"% enemyname)
                sleep(5)
            label.text="what are you going to do?"
            turn=True
            while True:
                sleep(0.1)
                if attacking==True:
                    turn=False
                    attacking==False
                    TextBox.type_text()
                    break
                elif guard==True:
                    turn=False
                    guard=False
                    guardcor==True
                    break
                elif healing==True:
                    turn=False
                    healing==False

                    break



class TextBox(BoxLayout):
    cache_text = StringProperty("") # For storing the entered text.
    index = NumericProperty(0) # For iteration over cache_text.
    global started
    global testify
    def hide_widget(self, wid, dohide=True):
        if hasattr(wid, 'saved_attrs'):
            if not dohide:
                wid.height, wid.size_hint_y, wid.opacity, wid.disabled = wid.saved_attrs
                del wid.saved_attrs
        elif dohide:
            wid.saved_attrs = wid.height, wid.size_hint_y, wid.opacity, wid.disabled
            wid.height, wid.size_hint_y, wid.opacity, wid.disabled = 0, None, 0, True

    def type_text(self, txt, time=0.06):
        global testify
        self.ids.label.text = ""  # Comment it out to retain the text.
        self.cache_text = txt # Store the entered text here.
        # For more control you may use method Clock.create_trigger.
        self.ev = Clock.schedule_interval(self.update_text, time) # Update text after every 0.25 sec.

    def update_text(self, *args):
            global testify
            if self.index < len(self.cache_text):
                val = self.cache_text[self.index]
                self.ids.label.text += val # Appending to existing text.
                self.index += 1
            else:
                self.index = 0 # Reset index.
                self.cache_text = "" # Clear cache.
                self.ev.cancel() # Cancel text updation.

    def on_button_click(self):
        global testify
        global started
        if started==False:
            started=True
            enemyname = self.ids.starta.text
            self.hide_widget(self.ids.starta)
            self.hide_widget(self.ids.startb)
            testify.insert(0,self.ids.label)
            testify.insert(1,self.ids.thingy)
            testify.insert(2,self.ids.thingys)
            testify.insert(3,self.ids.thingyss)
            testify.insert(4,enemyname)
            testify.insert(5,self)
            p = ProcessingThread()
            p.start()

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return TextBox()

TestApp().run()
```

also dont blame me if the script sucks I am new I started like 5 days ago (if you ask why one of the 3 labels from the "first" boxlayout's size is different other than the 2 other, it is for testing purposes)
[gui layout output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ev8AR.png)
[gui layout output 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFTyI.png)

Comment: You shouldn't use the default class name (here `BoxLayout`) as dynamic class name (also in general sense) in `kvlang`. I guess one of your `BoxLayout` might be `TextBox`. But this might not solve the issue completely (due to the presence of the other dynamic class. You may change its name and define it as a new dynamic class).

Comment: I have not understood much but I should like change the TextBox(**BoxLayout**) part if I am correct? Well if not would be real nice if you clarified things a little, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you define a rule in a `kv` file using `<SomeClass>`, that rule gets applied to every instance of that `SomeClass` that gets created after the `kv` file is loaded. If you have two different rules like `<SomeClass>`, then the second set of properties from the second rule just get added to the first.

If you want different properties, you can create different classes and define different `<>` rules. Or, you can define a single rule that contains two instances of the original `SomeClass`.

In your case you can do something like:

```
FloatLayout:
    TextBox: 
        # properties of the first TextBox
        .
        .
        .
    TextBox: 
        # properties of the second TextBox
        .
        .
        .
```

Of course, you will need to position and size the `TextBox` instances.

You can use a `<TextBox>` rule to define properties that will be common to all instances of `TextBox`.